# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null in chrome brwser

Tags: javascript

```
  var one = document.getElementById('num');
    var two = document.getElementById('nums');
    var sumadd = document.getElementById('last');

    one.addEventListener('input', myfun);
    two.addEventListener('input', myfun);

    function myfun() {
        var one1 = parseFloat(one.value) || 0;
        var two2 = parseFloat(two.value) || 0;
        var sumval = one1 + two2;
        sumadd.innerHTML = "The Sum of the two values are " +sumval;
    }



  <div id="footer">
        <input type="text" id="num"/> 
        <input type="text" id="nums" />
    <p id="last"></p>
    </div>
```

Please resolve the issue im getting this error in chrome browser. Not sure where the issue was

Comment: PLease include html

Comment: Looks like "num" and "nums" do not exist

Comment: `var one = document.getElementById('num');` and other similar lines execute before your html is completely loaded. To solve this issue, put those inside your `window.onload` method

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurring because one of your `getElementById()` calls is not returning anything. It is likely that you are missing html nodes that have the ids `num` or `nums`.

For example, having `<div id="num"></div>` in your html would return a valid object that you could run `addEventListener` on.

Answer (score 0):

You can wright this things in

```
window.onload = function(){


//script goes here 
}
```

or add this script in the end of body tag.